# Incorrect syntax near '=' while trying to call a stored procedure in T-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am calling a stored procedure called `Searchprocedure`. I get an error at line where I am calling it. I have not made any changes to the parameters passed in the procedure and it was called just fine with same calling statement earlier.

```
Exec SearchProcedure @firstname = 'Simran', @middlename = 'kaur', @lastname = 'Khurana', @City = 'Delhi'
```

What's wrong with the syntax that is gives the error that says:

> Incorrect syntax near '='

Edit:
 Statement where I did :

```
 set @sql = 'declare ' + '@Temp'+ @colVar + ' int'
    exec(@sql)
    select @sql as 'SQLFORDECLARATIONS 
outputs 


declare @TempMiddleName int
```

yet when I try to set value in the variable gives error that it should be declared first.

The set statement results in :

```
select  @TempMiddleName=dbo.[MatchMiddleName](MiddleNameFromUser,MiddleNameFromTable,0)
```

which is what is should be yet it not able to see the declared variable

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
create procedure SearchProcedure
(
   @firstname nvarchar(20),
   @middlename nvarchar(20) = null,
   @lastname nvarchar(20),
   @DOB Date = null,
   @SSN nvarchar(30)= null, 
   @ZIP nvarchar(10)= null,
   @StateOfResidence nvarchar(2)= null,
   @City nvarchar(20)= null,
   @StreetName nvarchar(20)= null,
   @StreetType nvarchar(20)= null,
   @BuildingNumber int= null,
   @Aptnumber nvarchar(10)= null
)
As 
DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(2000), @Where NVARCHAR(1000) = ' '
declare @Percent int,
@FN nvarchar(20),
@MN nvarchar(20) = null,
@LN nvarchar(20),
@DateOfB Date = null,
@SSNumber nvarchar(30)= null, 
@ZIPCode nvarchar(10)= null,
@StateOfRes nvarchar(2)= null,
@CityOfRes nvarchar(20)= null,
@StreetNameRes nvarchar(20)= null,
@StreetTypeRes nvarchar(20)= null,
@BuildingNumberRes int= null,
@AptnumberRes nvarchar(10)= null
set @Percent = 0
create table #results
(
firstname nvarchar(20) not null,
middlename nvarchar(20),
lastname nvarchar(20)not null,
PercentageMatch int not null,
DOB Date,
SSN nvarchar(30), 
ZIP nvarchar(10),
[State] nvarchar(2),
City nvarchar(20),
StreetName nvarchar(20),
StreetType nvarchar(20),
BuildingNumber int,
Aptnumber nvarchar(10)
 )

declare  c Cursor local static Read_only 
 for 
SELECT * from dbo.Patients where firstname = @firstname


open c

fetch next from c into @FN,
@MN,
@LN,
@DateOfB,
@SSNumber, 
@ZIPCode,
@StateOfRes,
@CityOfRes,
@StreetNameRes,
@StreetTypeRes,
@BuildingNumberRes,
@AptnumberRes

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

/*set @Percent = dbo.[MatchLastName](@lastname, @LN, @Percent)
set @Percent = dbo.[MatchMiddleName](@middlename, @MN, @Percent)
set @Percent = dbo.[MatchCity](@City, @CityOfRes, @Percent)*/
Exec [dbo].[OutputProcedure]  @lastname,  @LN, @middlename, @MN,@City, @CityOfRes, @Percent output
Insert into #results values 
(@FN,@MN,@LN,@Percent, @DateOfB,@SSNumber, @ZIPCode,@StateOfRes,@CityOfRes,@StreetNameRes,@StreetTypeRes,@BuildingNumberRes,@AptnumberRes)
fetch next from c into @FN,
@MN,
@LN,
@DateOfB,
@SSNumber, 
@ZIPCode,
@StateOfRes,
@CityOfRes,
@StreetNameRes,
@StreetTypeRes,
@BuildingNumberRes,
@AptnumberRes
end

select * from #results order by PercentageMatch desc
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #results
go
```

`OutputProcedure` code is as follows:

```
CREATE Procedure OutputProcedure
( 
 @LastNameFromUser nvarchar(20) = null, 
 @LastNameFromTable nvarchar(20), 
 @MiddleNameFromUser nvarchar(20) = null, 
 @MiddleNameFromTable nvarchar(20) = null, 
 @CityFromUser nvarchar(20) = null,
  @CityFromTable nvarchar(20) = null,
@Percentage int out
  )
AS
BEGIN
select 'OUTPUTPROCEDURECALLED'
declare @maxvalue int
DECLARE @variableTable TABLE (
    idx int identity(1,1),
    matchvalue nvarchar(15))

    INSERT INTO @variableTable(matchvalue) values ('MiddleName')
    INSERT INTO @variableTable(matchvalue) values ('LastName')
    INSERT INTO @variableTable(matchvalue) values ('City')

    SELECT * FROM @variableTable 
DECLARE @counter int
declare @sql nvarchar(100)
declare @sql2 nvarchar(25), @finalResult nvarchar(100)
declare @sql3 nvarchar(300), @sql4 nvarchar(15),  @tempresultStore nvarchar(20), @temp int, @temp2 int, @average int


SET @counter = 1
SELECT @maxvalue = (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM @variableTable)

select @maxvalue as 'MAXVALUE'
WHILE(@counter <= @maxvalue)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @colVar nvarchar(15)

    SELECT @colVar = matchvalue FROM @variableTable WHERE idx = @counter
    set @sql = 'declare ' + '@Temp'+ @colVar + ' int'
    exec(@sql)
    select @sql as 'SQLFORDECLARATIONS'

    /*set @temp = CHARINDEX(' ',@sql)
    select @temp as 'resultofcharindex'
    set @temp2 = LEN(@sql) - (@temp)
    SELECT @temp2 AS 'AFTERADDING1'
    set @tempresultStore = right(@sql, @temp2)*/
    set @tempresultStore = 'Temp'+@colVar
    SELECT @tempresultStore AS 'FINALCUTPART'

set @sql3 = 'set ' + ' ' + @tempresultStore + '=' + 'dbo.[Match' + @colVar + '](' + @colVar + 'FromUser' + ',' + @colVar + 'FromTable' + ',' + '0)' 
EXEC(@sql3)  
select @sql3 as 'check sql query formed'

set @finalResult = @finalResult + @tempresultStore
select @finalResult as 'SUM'
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
    select @counter as 'COUNTERVALUE'
    END
    set @Percentage = @finalResult/@maxvalue
    SELECT @Percentage AS 'FINALRESULT'
RETURN 
END
```

Comment: Can you add `[dbo].[Outputprocedure]` SP code

Comment: @NoDisplayName: Updated with OutputProcedureCode

Comment: Firstly when you build dynamic sql you have to know that each time you do an exec(@sql) its executed in a different session. SO you cannot do declare in a code then execute it then do something else. Build your whole dynamic code and execute it, if you have problems post an updated version of your procedure code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
--Setting variable in Dynamic SQL
DECLARE 
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Name NVARCHAR(100)

SET @Name = '#B2E0EB1A'
SET @sql = 
'
DECLARE @MyVar NVARCHAR(100)
SELECT TOP 1 @MyVar = name FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE ''%a''--Escaping single quote with double quote
PRINT @MyVar
'
EXEC(@sql)

SET @sql = 
'
DECLARE @MyVar NVARCHAR(100)
SET @MyVar = '''+(SELECT TOP 1 name FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE '%a')+'''--Escaping single quote with double quote
PRINT @MyVar
'
EXEC(@sql)

SET @sql = 
'
DECLARE @MyVar NVARCHAR(100)
SET @MyVar = '''+@Name+'''--Escaping single quote with double quote
PRINT @MyVar
'
EXEC(@sql)


SET @sql = 
'
DECLARE @MyVar NVARCHAR(100)
SET @MyVar = ''#B2E0EB1A''--Escaping single quote with double quote
PRINT @MyVar
'
EXEC(@sql)
```

If you want to get output variable from your dynamic query you have to use sp_executesql procedure instead of EXEC()

Study this code

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQLOutput NVARCHAR(100)   
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmeterDefinition nvarchar(500);

--in this variabe you write the variables which you want to be declared in the dynamic sql without using the declare
SET @ParmeterDefinition = N'@FinalOutputResultInDynamicSQL NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT';

--here you write your dynamic code
SELECT @SQL = N'SET @FinalOutputResultInDynamicSQL = ''test'' '


EXEC sp_executesql 
    @SQL, --Execute code
    @ParmeterDefinition, -- Define Parameters
    @FinalOutputResultInDynamicSQL = @DynamicSQLOutput OUTPUT --Get output
--Note that @FinalOutputResultInDynamicSQL is only defined in @ParmeterDefinition but not outside of the dynamic sql
PRINT @DynamicSQLOutput;
```

Comment: Thanks .That helped.But as you can see, I am infact using the input parameters of the procedure as the parameters passed in the function call while creating the dynamic sql query. So, how do I deal with it?

Comment: Thanks a ton. Almost got it. Just last question. I declared parameters in ParameterDefinition variable, how do I provide values to all of them?

Comment: If you put there more parameters obviously you need them so in your dynamic sql code you will assign values to them. Or i didnt understood your question.

Comment: Also indent your code better so you and everyone else that is reading your code can read it easier, name your variables, cursors,tables and in general all as descriptive as possible and last but not least put comments in your code not too much not too little.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any error and can run the exec without anerror message.

Edit: After I created the (now avialbe) output procedure and uncomment its call, I'm getting the error too...

Still investigating

Edit2:
In the Output procedure you have to use 
`set @sql = 'declare ' + '@Temp'+ @colVar + ' int'` (@ before Temp) and 
`set @sql3 = 'set ' + ' @' + @tempresultStore"` (additional @ after the 'set'.

Btw: you can exec more than one statement in Dynamic SQL so you could use f.e. `exec (@sql + '; ' + @sql3);`

Comment: Found it . It was in the dynamic SQL statement where I forgot to concatenate '@' symbol before the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I think too many things wrong in your `Dynamic sql`. I found one

```
SET @sql3 = 'set ' + ' ' + @tempresultStore + ' = ' + 'dbo.[Match'
                        + @colVar + '](' + @colVar + 'FromUser' + ',' + @colVar
                        + 'FromTable' + ',' + '0)'
```

In the above code instead of `Set` use `Select`. Looks like you are selecting from a `UDF`. Try this

```
SET @sql3 = 'Select ' + ' ' + @tempresultStore + ' = ' + 'dbo.[Match'
                        + @colVar + '](' + @colVar + 'FromUser' + ',' + @colVar
                        + 'FromTable' + ',' + '0)'
```

**Note :** To debug `Dynamic Sql` before `Exec @sql` just use `print @sql` to check the `syntax` and other stuff in generated `sql`

Comment: Oh, yes I am but that did not solve the problem either. Still it gives the same error

Comment: @sim - As i said you need to print the `@sql` and check, without seeing data it is hard to debug `Dynamic Sql`

Comment: Updated the question with statements resulting from dynamc sql.Please check. It does not look like there is error in the same. Clue that I have got so far from internet is that probably it is related to scope of  visibility in dynamic SQL